# How to display currency in Indian numbering format in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, currency-formatting

One of my client have real estate website to sell properties. It was built in wordpress using houzez theme. That website have default numbering system where the separator shows at every three characters eg: 10 lacks : 1,000,000 , but in indian currency format it should be like : 10,00,000 .

The Indian currency numbering system is looks like :

> 1
>   10
>   100
>   1,000
>   10,000
>   1,00,000
>   10,00,000
>   1,00,00,000
>   10,00,00,000

How do i change that numbering system in my wordpress website?
is there any plugin available?

Comment: you should ask this to support of your theme. general computing hardware and software are off-topic here

Comment: This is common problem in all themes which i have used. This issue is not dedicated to only the theme which i have mentioned,

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the function [numberToCurrencymad](https://gist.github.com/hitswa/e7f6ca5a72af2a480193540ad4bb0a75)e by hitswa

Then this function can be used in different ways:

1. Directly to the field: `<?php echo numberToCurrency( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'price', true ) ); ?>`
2. Apply a filter to the field assuming that your code to display the field is like this:

   `$unformatted_price = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'price', true);<br>
   echo apply_filters('price_meta_content', $unformatted_price );`

And on your functions.php `<?php add_filter( 'price_meta_content', 'numberToCurrency' ) ; ?>`

3. Another solution would be to add a filter to the_content

   add_filter('the_content','strnumtocurrency', 99);
   function strnumtocurrency($content){
     $pattern = "/(\d+.\d+)/";
      return  preg_replace( $pattern, numberToCurrency('$1'), $content );
   }

Here is the numberToCurrency code

```
<?php

function numberToCurrency($number)
{
    if(setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_IN'))
      return money_format('%.0n', $number);
    else {
      $explrestunits = "" ;
      $number = explode('.', $number);
      $num = $number[0];
      if(strlen($num)>3){
          $lastthree = substr($num, strlen($num)-3, strlen($num));
          $restunits = substr($num, 0, strlen($num)-3); // extracts the last three digits
          $restunits = (strlen($restunits)%2 == 1)?"0".$restunits:$restunits; // explodes the remaining digits in 2's formats, adds a zero in the beginning to maintain the 2's grouping.
          $expunit = str_split($restunits, 2);
          for($i=0; $i<sizeof($expunit); $i++){
              // creates each of the 2's group and adds a comma to the end
              if($i==0)
              {
                  $explrestunits .= (int)$expunit[$i].","; // if is first value , convert into integer
              }else{
                  $explrestunits .= $expunit[$i].",";
              }
          }
          $thecash = $explrestunits.$lastthree;
      } else {
          $thecash = $num;
      }
      if(!empty($number[1])) {
        if(strlen($number[1]) == 1) {
          return '₹ ' .$thecash . '.' . $number[1] . '0';
        } else if(strlen($number[1]) == 2){
          return '₹ ' .$thecash . '.' . $number[1];
        } else {
            return 'cannot handle decimal values more than two digits...';
        }
      } else {
        return '₹ ' .$thecash.'.00';
      }
    }
}

?>
```